# Choose the door - Number of coin tosses

Tags: probability

2 doors, behind one there is 1million € behind the other there is nothing, you want to pick the door where the money is. You have a coin which tells you where the money is 60% of the time. What's the probability you get the right door if you are allowed to toss the coin 1 time? What if u can toss the coin 2 times? If you can toss the coin 3 times? Similarly for 4 coin tosses? How can you improve your accuracy of picking the right door?

I saw this question as a popular interview question

I think for the 1st part where you toss 1 coin it would simply be 60%

Not sure how to proceed for the other parts tho

Assumption - The accuracy of each toss is independent of the other tosses

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that you'll need to state some assumptions.  is the accuracy of each toss independent of the other tosses?

Comment: One coin should indeed give $60\%$.  Multiple coins is the interesting question.  You could do the conditional probability calculations, but the interesting point for the interview is how the tosses make predictions.  If you ask two weather forecasters with the same training, methods and input data to make predictions, they may always give the same predictions as each other (so with the same accuracy) and so there is no benefit from asking the second one.

Comment: I think for 2 coin tosses it might be 0.84 as like Henry suggested you could simply choose to pick the door after the 1st toss (ignoring the 2nd toss) with probability of 0.6 or you can toss twice and have a strategy to pick the dor on the last coin toss. Then you have 2 different cases i.e. Door 1, Door 2 or Door 2, Door 1 and probability of each happening is 0.6*0.4. Now you have a 1/2 chance of picking the correct door which gives us 0.12 + 0.12 = 0.24 in addition to our 0.6 if we choose to just toss once. Not sure if this is right or makes sense.

Comment: Please include your efforts in the body of your post, not the comments.  As to what you wrote...well it's hard to follow.  What assumption are you making as regards independence?  What do you do if the two tosses yield different results?

Comment: A million dollar is the typical sum thrown away by the channels just because they can afford to throw it away. Brave new world ! This sad trend has also reached Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible strategies is to toss the coin $n$ times and choose the door which corresponds to the side of the coin which has been thrown more frequent than the other. Then the probability that your choice is correct will be:
$$
P=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil-1}\binom nk(1-p)^k p^{n-k}.
$$
For $p=0.6$ and $n=1\dots10$ one obtains

$P={0.6,0.36,0.648,0.4752,0.68256,0.54432,0.710208,0.594086,0.733432,0.633103}$.

As was pointed in the comments it is possible to improve the result for even $n$ if one chooses the door at random in the case of a tie. This will give the same probability of success as in the case of $n-1$ throws, i.e. instead of the above sequence we obtain:

$P=   {0.6,0.6,0.648,0.648,0.68256,0.68256,0.710208,0.710208,0.733432,0.733432}. 
$

Comment: could you give some further intuitive explanation on why this strategy is worse for $n=2$ than simply randomly selecting a coin?

Comment: For even $n$, when the two outcomes of a coin flip happen $n/2$ times each, what if we choose a door randomly (instead of going home and choosing neither)?

Comment: This formula correctly computes the probability of coins pointing at the correct door, **but it ignores the case of a draw when number of throws is even**. Whenever there's a draw the only way is to randomly pick a door, which gives 50% probability of success. So, [probability of a draw ] * 0.5 should be added to probability computed by @user's formula for each even number of throws.

Comment: If there is a tie you should pick a door at random.  For two coins this happens 0.48 of the time, adding 0.24 to your success rate and getting 0.60.  it is no better than one coin, but no worse.

Comment: @tyrrr I have added your suggestion.